# No TTY present when running commands over SSH in here-document

Tags: ssh, bash, sudo

I'm trying to run a command over SSH like this in a here-document:

```
ssh example.com <<END
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
END
```

Which normally works except when I'm trying to run something that needs input, such as the password for sudo. In that case, I'm getting the following message:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

I know I can use the `-t` flag on SSH to allocate a pseudo-tty such as this:

```
ssh -t example.com "sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload"
```

And it'll work, but when I try the same thing with here-document, it doesn't work and I'll get the same error about no tty being present:

```
ssh -t example.com <<END
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
END
```

Any idea how I can make this work?

Also, in case you are wondering why I want it to work with the here-document instead of just passing it on the same line, it is because the input commands (there can be a few) come from a configuration file read by a script and I've heard it avoids the trouble of escaping the commands for the quotes, double quotes, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `visudo` to edit the sudoers file and insert a below line:

```
Defaults:<user>    !requiretty
```

---

> It doesn't answer why using the `ssh -t "something" versus ssh -t
>   <<STOP something STOP` doesn't work. Let's say I'm not using sudo but
>   I'm using passwd for my own user directly, I still won't get the TTY
>   using the heredoc.

Try `ssh -t -t` to force pseudo-tty allocation even if stdin is not a terminal.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen this fix elsewhere, but it only goes around the problem for the commands that use sudo. It doesn't answer why using the ssh -t "something" versus ssh -t <<STOP something STOP doesn't work. Let's say I'm not using sudo but I'm using passwd for my own user directly, I still won't get the TTY using the heredoc.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply store the here document in a variable that will be given `ssh -t` as a command argument.

On a more general note, use `ssh -T` or specify the remote shell as a command argument if the stdin of the remote host is being redirected from a heredoc (to prevent `ssh` from trying to allocate a pty).

```
# store heredoc in a variable
heredoc="$(cat <<EOF
who
sudo ls -ld /
logname
EOF
)"

ssh -t localhost "$heredoc"


# avoid: Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
- ssh example.com <<END
+ ssh -T example.com <<END
+ ssh example.com /bin/sh <<END
```