# x11vnc through SSH tunnel - sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Tags: ssh, vnc, sudo, x11

I'm trying to setup a one-time SSH tunnel which instantiates x11vnc on a logged-in display.

```
ssh -f -t -L 5900:localhost:5900 user@10.1.10.1 'sudo /usr/bin/x11vnc -safer -once -nopw -display :0 -auth /home/user/.Xauthority'
```

/etc/sudoers:

```
user@myhost:~$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers
[sudo] password for user: 
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/
# instead of directly modifying this file.
#
Defaults:user   !requiretty
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
user  ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/x11vnc

%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

The end result is this:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener: cannot listen to port: 5900
Could not request local forwarding.
ebz@icarus:~ $ sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Sorry, try again.
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Sorry, try again.
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

It does say `bind: Address already in use`, but I feel this is not true and unrelated:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 10.1.10.1:domain        *:*                     LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 xxxx::xxxx:xxxx::domain [::]:*                  LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN      -
```

Safe to say we can ignore that message. Also, removing the sudo entry for user has no effect, either.

Thanks, guys. Cheers.

P.S. The solution here - [No TTY present when running commands over SSH..](https://serverfault.com/questions/315150/no-tty-present-when-running-commands-over-ssh-in-here-document) - didn't work :(

Also, a side note, THIS IS SERVER RELATED (BACKGROUND REGARDING A CUSTOM LXC VMM IMPLEMENTATION FOR OPENNEBULA). Please DO NOT mark this off-topic as this is a valid application use case.

**UPDATE**

Plus `-tt`, minus `-f -t` switches:

```
$ ssh -tt -L 5900:localhost:5900 user@10.1.10.1 'sudo /usr/bin/x11vnc -safer -once -nopw -display :0 -auth /home/user/.Xauthority'
bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener: cannot listen to port: 5900
Could not request local forwarding.
[sudo] password for user:
```

But it prompts for a password? It works after I enter the password though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that `user` isn't in either of the groups `admin` or `sudo` or put the sudoers line for `user` after the group lines.

From the sudoers man page

> When multiple entries match for a user, they are applied in order. Where there are multiple matches, the last match is used (which is not necessarily the most specific match).