# How can I give tomcat sudo right

Tags: linux, security, sudo, tty, login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No TTY present when running commands over SSH in here-document](https://serverfault.com/questions/315150/no-tty-present-when-running-commands-over-ssh-in-here-document)

I installed tomcat7. It is nologin user tomcat7. That said, I need to give tomcat7 sudo rights to run other applications.

I edit sudoer. But requiretty is set, sudo will only run when the user is logged in to a real tty. However tomcat is nologin...

What should I do?

Comment: giving tomcat7 sudo rights to run other applications is not advised; try to see if you have no other workaround.

Comment: @thinice OP never said it would give root to tomcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is to edit /etc/sudoers and add

```
Defaults:tomcat7    !requiretty
```

, like stated in [No TTY present when running commands over SSH in here-document](https://serverfault.com/questions/315150/no-tty-present-when-running-commands-over-ssh-in-here-document) and [sudoers: how to disable requiretty per user](https://serverfault.com/questions/111064/sudoers-how-to-disable-requiretty-per-user)